# An improper integral involving Modified Bessel Function of the second kind

Tags: improper-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

I've come across the following integral involving the Bessel Functions $K_\nu$ that would be great if it were possible to evaluate.

$$\int_{y_1}^{\infty}dy\frac{y}{\sqrt{a^2+y^2}} \left(\left[K_0\left(m \sqrt{a^2+y^2}\right)+K_2\left(m \sqrt{a^2+y^2}\right)\right] \left[y-\mathrm{arctan}\left(\frac{y}{a}\right)\right] +2 y K_1\left(m \sqrt{a^2+y^2}\right)\right)$$

Here m is a real parameter greater than 0.

I'm having trouble using any table of integrals or Mathematica, since the bounds of integration are not from $0 \rightarrow \infty$, and I can't find how to get closed form expressions for any of the parts' integrals.

Even being able to evaluate any term in this expression could be very helpful, and any resources on where these have been done would be appreciated.

Comment: The substitution $r = \sqrt{a^2 +y^2}$ and $dr = \frac{y}{ \sqrt{a^2 +y^2}} dy$ should make at least the first term tractable; Wolfram Alpha produces a result for the indefinite integral. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+BesselK%280%2C+m+r%29+dr .  That substitution also results in $\mathrm{arctan}(y/a) = \mathrm{arccos}(a/r)$ (be careful with angle signs though), so along with $y = \sqrt{r^2 - a^2}$ maybe there is some hope for the other terms.

Comment: Thanks. But the issue is that that those terms are being multiplied by additional terms $y$. So that substitution would result in trying to integrate $K_0(x) \sqrt{x^2-a^2}$, which doesn't have an indefinite integral.

Comment: Oops.  I misread the parentheses.  I've submitted an edit to change to adaptive size parentheses and alternate with brackets.